# How do you iterate over all variables in an Angular $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this controller:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
     $scope.foo = true;
     $scope.bar = false;
}
```

Is there any way to access each of these scope variables through iteration. Something like:

```
for (i in $scope.variables){
    var v = $scope.variables[i];
    console.log(v.name, v.value);
}
```

where the output would be:

```
foo true
bar false
```

In addition to reading the values of the variables like this, is there any way to assign values to them through iteration as well.

Comment: Shouldn't `for (let key in $scope)` do what you are asking for?

Comment: try `(Object.keys($scope)).forEach(function(key){ } );`

Comment: Yes, the above approaches  were what I needed. Thank you.